# Не обновляется Visual Studio 2017

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017

При нажатии на обновить, появляется установщик, далее я нажимаю UPDATE и ничего не происходит.

В Event'ах пишется вот это:

> Application: vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address
>   00007FF80007FD0C
>
> Faulting application name: vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe, version:
>   15.0.345.18999, time stamp: 0x58e7da9d Faulting module name: d3d9.dll, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x631de416 Exception code:
>   0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x000000000000fd0c Faulting process id: 0xa38
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d2bc3e9aa30ee8 Faulting
>   application path:
>   C:\Users\iluxa\AppData\Local\Temp\4318329eed56a023203f5a4b\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d9.dll Report Id:
>   22a1d3ee-5b8b-49bc-b08e-2dbd68bfb069 Faulting package full name:
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> Fault bucket 120742804638, type 4 Event Name: APPCRASH Response: Not
>   available Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe P2: 15.0.345.18999
>   P3: 58e7da9d P4: d3d9.dll P5: 10.0.15063.0 P6: 631de416 P7: c0000005
>   P8: 000000000000fd0c P9: P10:
>
> Attached files:
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER782D.tmp.mdmp
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7A70.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7A73.tmp.csv
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7A94.tmp.txt
>
> These files may be available here:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_vs_setup_bootstr_3533e428f5139cda8118802eff68d253342f8bb_a4e4d05e_45e7828e
>
> Analysis symbol: Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
>   22a1d3ee-5b8b-49bc-b08e-2dbd68bfb069 Report Status: 268435456 Hashed
>   bucket: ccdf61ff7adbd46ebc6a165aba200552

ОС Windows 10 с последними обновлениями.

Чем-то d3d9.dll не устраивает апдейтер судя по журналу... Если я не ошибаюсь, то это DirectX. Скачал установщик DirectX с офф сайта и мне написали, что у меня последняя версия.

sfc не нашел поврежденных системных файлов

Что можно попробовать?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение:

Оказывается, проблемы была в том, что обновление Windows 10 Creators Update не очень хорошо дружит с MSI Afterburner и RivaTunerStatisticServer.

Если отключить данные программы, то проблем нет.